# :class Unexpected token issue in testcafe in vue app

Tags: vue.js, testing, integration-testing, testcafe, babel-polyfill

I am trying to run test integration in Vue app
and I am importing component in components.test.js but it gives an Unexpected token error

components.test.js

```
import flushPromises from "flush-promises";
import {Selector} from "testcafe";
import sample_vue from "../src/components/sample-vue.vue";
```

[image]

anyone can suggest?

**update** : if I use v-bind:class="" then I am facing new error

[image]

Comment: It is not clear why you import a Vue component into a test file. Could you please describe your scenario in greater detail?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add v-bind:

```
v-bind:class="{ error: !nameValidation }"
```

What you just wrote is supported in Nuxt js.

Comment: Yes I tried but now I am getting new error on option.name
<label v-bind:for="option.item">{{ option.name }}</label>

Comment: It's mean that works!
@ParthJasani edit your post so I can see your error & help you to resolve it!

Answer (score 1):

To use loop in Vue.js, you should probably do this:

```
<label v-for="(item, i) in option.item" :key="i">{{ item }}</label> // Or whatever you wanna use
```

It may not work because I do not know the `typeof` **option.item** or what it contains

Comment: no, its not for loop its a label attribute for input box

Comment: options: [
            { item: "A", name: "Option A" },
            { item: "B", name: "Option B" },
            { item: "C", name: "Option C", notEnabled: true },
            { item: "D", name: "Option D" },
         ],

Comment: Everything seems good, I have no idea about this, sorry!